# Formulario de busca Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

Gostaria de saber como faço para filtrar meus dados do banco com um formulario onde contem mais de 1 campo para filtrar, apenas consegui fazer com um campo apenas.

Form:

```
<form action="{{ url('panel/brands') }}" method="GET" name="frm_filter_brand" role="search">
    <div class="row ls-clearfix">
        <div class="ls-box-filter">
            <div class="row ls-clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="ls-label">
                        <b class="ls-label-text">ID</b>
                        <div class="ls-field-md">
                            <input class="uppercase" name="id" id="id" placeholder="Ex.: 10" type="text" value="">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="ls-label">
                        <b class="ls-label-text">Nome</b>
                        <div class="ls-field-md">
                            <input class="uppercase" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ex.: FORD" type="text" value="">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="ls-label">
                        <b class="ls-label-text">Descrição</b>
                        <div class="ls-field-md">
                            <input class="uppercase" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Ex.: Novas" type="text" value="">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <label style="margin-top:16px" class="ls-label ls-float-right">
                        <label class="ls-label">
                            <button id="btn-filter" type="submit" class="ls-btn ls-btn-filtrar">Filtrar</button>
                        </label>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Minha controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {            
        $filter_id = $request->id;
        if($filter_id){
            $brands = $this->brand::where('id', $filter_id)->get();
        }else{
            $brands = $this->brand::all();
        }      
        return view('brand.index', compact('brands'));
    }
```

Assim gostaria de verificar quais valores eu inseri nos filtros e fazer a busca com os mesmos.

Comment: Você quer criar mais de uma condição com o `where` utilizando os inputs do formulário, é isso?

Comment: isso mesmo, porem da forma que vc indicou, se eu filtrar apenas pelo "ID" não vai entrar na condição certo?
if($filter_id && $filter_name && $filter_description){

Comment: A ideia é que você possua as três variáveis para fazer o `where` corretamente. Por este motivo eu modifiquei a condição. As variáveis podem vir vazias?

Comment: sim podem, penso que o caso seria:
-receber os dados do form
-verificar quais foram inseridos
-realizar a busca somente com os informados

Comment: [Alterei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244803/5043), verifique se funciona...

Comment: muito bem, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda bio! abç

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar um array de condições dentro do `where` do seu Query Builder utilizando as variáveis dos inputs do seu formulário. Talvez algo do tipo:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{            
    $filter_id = $request->id;
    $filter_name = $request->name;
    $filter_description = $request->description;

    // cria o array que será utilizado no query builder
    $filter_all;

    // verifica se veio id
    if($filter_id) {
        $filter_all[] = ['id', '=', $filter_id];
    }

    // verifica se veio name
    if($filter_name) {
        $filter_all[] = ['name', 'like', '%'.$filter_name.'%'];
    }

    // verifica se veio o description
    if($filter_description) {
        $filter_all[] = ['description', 'like', '%'.$filter_description.'%'];
    }

    // verifica se há valores para utilizarmos no 'where'
    if(isset($filter_all)){
        $brands = $this->brand::where($filter_all)->get();
    }else{
        $brands = $this->brand::all();
    }      

    return view('brand.index', compact('brands'));

}
```